# Run Goglang with aws-vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, goland

I use aws-vault to establish a secure sesssion to my dev AWS env in ZSH, all good.  Now I want to run my IDE (Gogland) such that it assumes that aws-vault session so that I can then in turn debug some tests that have a dependency on S3.

How can I can a process (such as Gogland) so that it inherits the aws-vault session? I have tried simply starting Gogland from the shell after having established a vault session to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Tools | Create Command-line Launcher...` and it will ask you where it should create that launcher. By default it's `/usr/local/bin/gogland` but if that is not writable by your user, create it in your user Home directory and then move it in the above mentioned place or another place in your PATH.

Then run `aws-vault exec home -- gogland` and this should set the environment variables for Gogland to inherit. If you are using the [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/), which I highly recommend, then you need to launch the Toolbox instead of the so that it can then launch the IDE with the correct environment variables.

Comment: This is not very friendly for a multi-project environment. One where one project should be associated (and deployed) to one AWS profile and another to another profile.